# Need help in converting old php code to php 7.4.2

Tags: php

Below is the small block of code in old version of php.
It have some deprecated methods can anyone help me to convert them into PHP 7 compatible PDO methods.

```
    // Delete the message residing at the tail end of their list so they cannot archive more than 100 PMs ..................
$sqldeleteTail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE to_id = '$to' ORDER BY time_sent DESC LIMIT 0,100");
    $dci = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqldeleteTail)){
        $pm_id = $row['memberID'];
        if ($dci > 99){
            $deleteTail = mysql_query("DELETE FROM private_msg WHERE id='$pm_id'");
        }
        $dci++;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only thing deprecated I can see in that code are those mysql_* calls, but since you say that you can change those, what is the question/issue? What have you actually tried?

Comment: the PDO equivalent of `mysql_fetch_array` is [`fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the updated code as per PHP 7 and above

```
  // $conn is the instance of your database connection here.
$sqldeleteTail = "SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE to_id = '$to' ORDER BY time_sent DESC LIMIT 0,100";
$dci = 1;
foreach ($conn->query($sqldeleteTail) as $row) {
    $pm_id = $row['memberID'];
    if ($dci > 99){
        $deleteTail ="DELETE FROM private_msg WHERE id='$pm_id'";
        $conn->query($deleteTail);
    }
    $dci++;
}
```

I hope it'll help you

Comment: The OP specifically say that they change it to PDO, not mysqli.

Comment: I think he is just using PDO. If he only wanted in PDO then he would've already mentioned it. I hope i'm not wrong or missing something

Comment: He said that he used PDO statement.It's not that he wants it PDO specifically. Let him decide if he wants it or not. And thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: _"He said that he used PDO statement"_ - Exactly. Why would they make _another_ connection to the database with a completely different API for _some_ requests? That would be crazy and really bad design.

Comment: Okay bro Got it !.

Comment: Should I delete the answer ??

Comment: ...or just change it to use PDO. Just make sure to use prepared statements instead of injecting completely unescaped user data directly into the query.

Comment: Okay. will be doing that shortly

Comment: that code works perfectly thank you. some of the code was changed to mysqli and some PDO but I have spent the week converting it all to PDO, just seens easier to keep it all thesame rather than having a mix of the two.

Comment: Khalid Khan no please don't delete it, the code is working fine. thanks once again. I did struggle with this for about 5 - 6 days.

Comment: It's my pleasure bro to help you. @Dion